# Category theory as a foundation for mathematics

Tags: category-theory

Can Category theory form a foundation for mathematics like set theory and mathematical logic and if it can is there a way to know if that theory will be both consistent and complete

Comment: If you're asking whether it will be consistent and complete, then presumably you know about Gödel, but if you know about Gödel, then you know it will not be consistent and complete… My guess is that you're asking whether category theory might be able to sneak around the hypotheses of the incompleteness theorem?

Comment: I understand that Goedel prescribed his proof to apply to a sufficiently "strong theory of arithmetic" is category theory such a theory??

Comment: Strong means able to construct $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @EricStucky, Yeah that's right

Comment: The only way you might possibly get around this is that (I believe) Gödel rests on first-order logic, and it is at least conceivable that you could get around that, but such a system would probably be very, very strange. Notably, it seems unlikely that category theory in particular would play any special role; although it could provide a pretty font. I would be interested in what an actual set theorist has to say about foundations without FOL? Perhaps HoTT is a candidate?

Comment: [this is a response to a comment which was deleted] I will not claim to know the technicalities of Gödel, but I do know that the hypotheses are stupidly weak. Certainly any theory "containing" (maybe "describing" is better) $\Bbb N$ which uses FOL is subject to it. But it also holds without LEM, so even in the presence of weakened FOL-like foundations it still holds. To get away from it you would move into radically different systems than we've used before, and it's not clear that any interesting mathematics exists out there.

Comment: Category theory is based on set theory (if it wasn't, we could have our category of all categories, but set theory says we can't!)

Comment: Is ETCS what you are looking for?